# How to avoid resetting the owin cookie timeout for a specific request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I have an application that is using Asp.net Identity with sliding expiration enabled true. When user logged in, I will get the cookie expire time out time from the server using WEB api and set session time out in JavaScript variable.The java script timer started running. If user continuously doing operations the pop will not be shown. If user is in idle, before showing session expire popup I will make request again to the server and get the cookie expire time out(some times users may able to use the system without refresh, doing only ajax requests).I will check with login timeout with current timeout based on that I will show the expire popup.

But When I check this, cookie time has been reset. How can I avoid resetting the cookie timeout on specific request?

```
    [HttpGet]      
    public int GetCookieExpireTime()
    {
        var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var claimType = "myExpireUtc";  
        if (identity != null && identity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == claimType))
        {
            var expireOn = identity.FindFirstValue(claimType);

            DateTimeOffset currentUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            DateTimeOffset? expireUtc = new DateTimeOffset(long.Parse(expireOn), TimeSpan.Zero);

            var remaining = (expireUtc.Value - currentUtc).TotalSeconds;

            return Convert.ToInt32(remaining);
        }
        return 0;
    }


function ShowPendingTimeoutDialog() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: loc + '/Home/GetCookieExpireTime',
    success: function (timeout) {
        var warnSec = msecWarning / 1000;
        //reset session timer if warn sec less than total time out time
        if (warnSec < timeout) {
            getCookieExpireTime();
        }
            //otherwise show session popup
        else {
            diag.dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: "Session About to Expire",
                closeText: "hide",
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Continue: function () {
                        ResetTimeout();
                    }
                },
                create: function () {
                    $(this).closest('div.ui-dialog')
                           .find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')
                           .click(function (e) {
                               ResetTimeout();
                           });
                    $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
                .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
                .html("<span class='ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick'></span>");
                }
            });
            UpdateTimeoutMessage();
            diag.dialog("open");
        }

    },
    failure: function () {

    }
});

function ResetTimeout() {
diag.dialog("close");
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: loc + '/KeepSessionAlive.ashx',
    success: function () {
        getCookieExpireTime();
    },
    failure: function () {

    }
});
```

Comment: Any updates on this? Have the same problem.